# How to Version Plugins

Tags: plugins, versioning

**I wonder how to version plugins.**

There are plenty ways of [versioning a software products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) but they're all 1-dimensional.

Are there best practices for 2-dimensional versioning which indicates both compatibility to the main application and compatibility to the plugin API?

---

Eclipse for example proposed a [versioning scheme](https://eclipse.org/equinox/documents/plugin-versioning.html) for which every plugin uses semantic versioning. Additionally there's a rule to distinguish between development streams by increasing the service number by 100. This ends in versions like that:

- Plugin version `v1.0.8` for Eclipse `v3.1`
- Plugin version `v1.0.108` for Eclipse `v3.2`

This seems a bit fishy to me. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to show the information about main application version in version of plugin? Does it help users to choose a suitable one?

I prefer put this information in a plugin name. For example, *plugin-eclipse31-1.0.8* and *plugin-eclipse32-1.0.8*. You can put branch name (*eclipse31* or *eclipse32* in examples) in plugin version, to make things easier.